# VBA Copy a Worksheet to a New Sheet without Formulas

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to copy whatever selected sheet (notwithstanding the name of the sheet) within the same workbook. First, I have tried the code of copying and renaming a new sheet (with formulas) that I found elsewhere. It is working well:

```
Public Sub CopySheetAndRename()
    Dim newName As String
     On Error Resume Next
    newName = InputBox("Enter the name for the copied worksheet")
     If newName <> "" Then
        ActiveSheet.Copy After:=Worksheets(Sheets.Count)
        On Error Resume Next
        ActiveSheet.Name = newName
    End If
End Sub
```

---

However, I would just like to have the newly created sheet without formulas. I tried to add the lines like: ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
but it is not working at all. I have read also this post [Copy Excel sheet to another excel book without formulas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39799241/copy-excel-sheet-to-another-excel-book-without-formulas) without any result.
Thank you for your help!

Stanley

Comment: `Worksheets(newName).Cells.Value = Worksheets(newName).Cells.Value`

Comment: BTW: `On Error Resume Next` basically turns off the error notification.  It does not automatically turn back on on after the next line.  the use of `On Error Resume Next` should be limited, instead deal with the errors and work around them.

Comment: Sometimes `Worksheets(newName).Cells.Value = Worksheets(newName).Cells.Value` gives a "out of memory error". best to use `Worksheets(newName).UsedRange.Value = Worksheets(newName).UsedRange.Value`

Comment: Thanks! It is working now with a text flaw, though. The formulas are removed but if there is a text with a bullet point in a cell in the original sheet such as 
·  Project Code"
The text in the newly copied sheet turns to Greek alphabet (which I cannot copy because copying here into forum turns it again into Latin "project code" with a bullet point as the first sign in the cell. Any ideas?