# Copy active sheet to new workbook without formulas

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to copy the active sheet (notwithstanding the name of the sheet) to a new WorkBook to be saved without a formula. A copy of the sheet to a new sheet is working according to [VBA Copy a Worksheet to a New Sheet without Formulas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59773278/vba-copy-a-worksheet-to-a-new-sheet-without-formulas) with some additions to the code:

```
Public Sub CopySheetAndRename()
Dim newName As String
 On Error Resume Next
newName = InputBox("Enter the name for the copied worksheet")
 If newName <> "" Then
    ActiveSheet.Copy After:=Worksheets(Sheets.Count)
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveSheet.Name = newName
    Worksheets(newName).UsedRange.Value = Worksheets(newName).UsedRange.Value
End If
End Sub
```

-- Then I tried to add the dialogbox 
    Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show
before "end if" and change "ActiveSheet.Name" to "ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name" but it does not work. (Or at least it copies the sheet into a new workbook but does not transfer the values). Any ideas on how to run the code? Thank you in advance!

Comment: `ActiveSheet.Copy After:=Worksheets(Sheets.Count)` doesn't copy a sheet into a new workbook though.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using the implicit copying function.
Try this out:

```
Activesheet.Copy
'Entire sheet is now on the clipboard
NewSheet.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
'Paste refers to the method of pasting, you can paste using any of the xlPasteXXX 
types'
```

`NewSheet` refers to a sheet object that contains the new sheet.
If you need to create a new sheet then simply declare a sheet object and set it to the new sheet
Example:

```
dim ws as worksheet
set ws = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets.Count)
```

If you need to add a new workbook that is different code, but google is your friend in that situation!